# Gatsby Issue - on load and on refresh I am seeing a flicker of unstyled components

Tags: css, gatsby, styling, gatsby-plugin

Issue - When I first load the page or I refresh the page, I get a flash of ugly un-styled features such as massive images, links go back to the custom styling of blue text with an underline, etc) before my own CSS applies.

Here is my package.json file -

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-hello-world",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simplified bare-bones starter for Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^1.6.22",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.12.0",
    "gatsby": "^2.26.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^1.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.9.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^1.5.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.9.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.5.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.6.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.6.1",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.7.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.1.2"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Here is my gatsby-config file -

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Gatsby Project",
    description: "",
    image: "/logo.png",
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
      options: {
        extensions: [`.mdx`, `.md`],
        gatsbyRemarkPlugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: { maxWidth: 1200 },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [`roboto-mono`, `muli\:400,400i,700,700i`],
        display: "swap",
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        icon: `src/images/logo.png`,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Am I missing a dependancy or is there a mistake in my config? Not sure..

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the browser's console prompting any log? Does it happen in all pages?

Comment: Yes it happens in all pages and there is no errors or prompts in the console :( @FerranBuireu

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this kind of issue related to styled-components (known as FOUT, **F**lash **o**f **U**nstyled **T**ext) is solved by checking missing configurations but in your case, it seems that you have everything properly set in your `gatsby-config.js` and you have all packages installed.

One thing you can try is removing the `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts` since usually when dealing with font-face blocks the rendering while loading the JavaScript. According to https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader:

> Using the Web Font Loader asynchronously avoids blocking your page
> while loading the JavaScript. Be aware that if the script is used
> asynchronously, the rest of the page might render before the Web Font
> Loader is loaded and executed, which can cause a Flash of Unstyled
> Text (FOUT).

If the issue is solved by removing this, you may need to find another way to add the fonts globally.

*Credits: [@LekoArts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10164092/lekoarts) in this [Spectrum topic](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/gatsby-ssr-and-flicker-re-render-on-initial-load%7E7b865415-01c3-40e7-8a3b-7966756f6cf4)*